# sort specific field last modified date

Tags: 7, views

I have content type named recipe, Recipe have some fields like name, image, description. And also have a Boolean field name editors picks. I want to get last checked 3 posts of editors picks field in a view. or i want to limit this field can check only in 3 post. How can i do this. Please help me

Comment: Maybe you could sort them by modified/updated date and limit the view to display only three results.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. How could i sort by modified date i already limit the view for three result. I cant understand how to get last modified content in view

Comment: I don't remember how is in drupal 7 but if you search at the sort criteria something that has to do with update or changed you will find it. At D8 is 'changed' for example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I searched for SORT CRITERIA to sort by last modified date there is a field named "Content revision: Updated date". This field helped me to sort by modified date.

Credits: [@ismini](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/74776/ismini) (for posting the comments that helped me).